# Is there a better solution to this 2D noise() ellipse in p5js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, perlin-noise

I am trying to find a way to show an ellipse on the scteen that moves according to noise. However, every noise tutorial that I found even for 2D shows just one output. I ended up having to change the noiseSeed() between lines. Is there a better solution for this, or a noise function that gives two different values even with the same seed? I used p5.js.

```
var t = 0;
var t2 = 0;
var t3;
var t4;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  t3 = random(1000);
  t4 = random(1000);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  noiseSeed(t3);
  var x = noise(t);
  noiseSeed(t4);
  var y = noise(t2);
  t += 0.01;
  t2 += 0.01;
  x = map(x, 0, 1, 0, width);
  y = map(y, 0, 1, 0, height);
  ellipse(x, y, 20, 20)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call `noise()` from the same Perlin seed but at different values, offset by some constant. x and y would not be independently random, but it wouldn't be very noticeable.

```
var x = noise(t);
var y = noise(t + someConstantValue);
t += 0.1;
```

Unfortunately, Perlin noise mirrors at 0, so adding to `t` and subtracting from `t2` would result in them being equal.

Note that Perlin noise repeats every 256 coordinates, so your constant should be smaller than that. 256/2 would be the furthest removed value from `t`, in this case.